# Changing R's Seed from Rcpp to Guarantee Reproducibility

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to write a function r(d, n) in rcpp. The function returns n random draws from normal distribution N(0, d). This function should be well defined, therefore the function should return the same draws whenever the d and n do not change their value.

This won't be a problem if d is restricted to be integer, in which case I can set seed and do the job

```
// set seed
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void set_seed(unsigned int seed) {
  Rcpp::Environment base_env("package:base");
  Rcpp::Function set_seed_r = base_env["set.seed"];
  set_seed_r(seed);  
}

// function r(d, n)
// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec randdraw(int d, int n){
  set_seed(d);
  vec out = randn(n);
  return out;
}
```

But clearly I don't want to restrict d to be integer. Ideally d should be double. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a very odd function. Comparing any two float values for equality is dangerous so it would be hard to ensure the same values are returned. Buy maybe you want to [memoise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html) the function.

Comment: You need to post the code of your attempt.

Comment: A well-defined function in my mind has nothing to do with returning the same draws with the same parameters, especially one that is dealing with draws from any PRNG. If you are concerned about your function being *predictable*, I suggest you either include an argument `seed` and call `set.seed(seed)` early in your function, or require the calling environment to handle the seeds directly. `Rcpp` allows this as well ([one of several references](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/set_rs_seed_in_rcpp_sequential_case/)).

Comment: @coatless Thank you. I just post the code (actually it was the code from one of your posts)

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. Maybe the term well-defined is not quite proper here. My intention is to give the same draws when the parameter is the same, and I post the attempt of using seed. The problem is seed is restricted to be integer, but the parameter need not be integer

Comment: Interesting thought. I do not understand what you are trying to do *mathematically*. PRNGs seem to always accept a standard array of arguments: `n` as an integer, the number of numbers to return, and other parameters that define the distribution itself. For example, `rnorm` accepts `mean` and `sd`, since those are the components of that parametric distribution. You are asking for `d` which is just a seed that has no impact on the distribution itself. Perhaps you just need a function that maps the input `numeric` consistently with an `integer`? `trunc`, perhaps?

Comment: (If `trunc` is unsatisfactory, you should state/define your expectation of a one-to-one mapping, such that one and only one input `d` can result in a specific output. In that case, I think the answer is "ain't gonna happen", but it's certainly possible that I'm missing something.)

Answer (score 7):

The issue that I think is happening is you are trying to disperse the `randn` offered by *Armadillo* that is restricted to being a standard normal, e.g. N(0,1), such that it matches N(0, d). There are two ways to go about this since it is a standard normal.

#### Option 1: Using Statistical Properties

The first way involves just multiplying the sample by the square root of `d`, e.g.  `sqrt(d)*sample`. This is possible due to the random variable properties of variance and expectation giving sqrt(d)*N(0, 1) ~ N(0, sqrt(d)^2) ~ N(0, d).

One of the more important things to note here is that the `set_seed()` function will work since the *Armadillo* configuration of [*RcppArmadillo* hooks into *R*'s RNG library](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/650401122d9ea7c43e2f20b2d17bf2e2bf1797f4/inst/include/RcppArmadillo/Alt_R_RNG.h#L81-L100) to access the `::Rf_runif` function to generate random values. The only area of concern is you cannot use `arma::arma_rng::set_seed()` to set the seed due to limitations of the R/C++ interaction detailed in [Section 6.3 of Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Random-numbers). If you do use this, then [you would get warned with](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/650401122d9ea7c43e2f20b2d17bf2e2bf1797f4/inst/include/RcppArmadillo/Alt_R_RNG.h#L61-L70) :

> When called from R, the RNG seed has to be set at the R level via set.seed()

on the first detected call.

With this being said, here is a short code example where we multiple by `sqrt(d)`.

Code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// set seed
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void set_seed(double seed) {
    Rcpp::Environment base_env("package:base");
    Rcpp::Function set_seed_r = base_env["set.seed"];
    set_seed_r(std::floor(std::fabs(seed)));
}

// function r(d, n)
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec randdraw(double d, int n){
    set_seed(d);              // Set a seed for R's RNG library
    // Call Armadillo's RNG procedure that references R's RNG capabilities
    // and change dispersion slightly.
    arma::vec out = std::sqrt(std::fabs(d))*arma::randn(n);
    return out;
}
```

Output:

```
> randdraw(3.5, 5L)
           [,1]
[1,] -0.8671559
[2,] -1.9507540
[3,]  2.9025090
[4,] -1.2953745
[5,]  2.0799176
```

Note: There is no direct equivalent as the `rnorm` procedure differs from the `arma::randn` generation.

#### Option 2: Rely upon *R*'s RNG Functions

The second, and significantly better solution, is to explicitly rely upon *R*'s RNG functions. Previously, we made an *implicit* use of *R*'s RNG library due to *RcppArmadillo*'s configuration. I tend to prefer this approach as you have already made an assumption that the code is specific to *R* when using [the `set_seed()` function](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/set-rs-seed-in-rcpp-sequential-case/) (**Disclaimer: I wrote the post**). If you are worried about the restriction of `d` being an `integer`, a slight coercion from `double` to `int` is possible with `std::floor(std::fabs(seed))`. Once the values are generated using either `Rcpp::r*()` or `R::r*()` , an armadillo vector is created using [an advanced ctor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) that reuses the existing memory allocation.

Code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// set seed
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void set_seed(double seed) {
    Rcpp::Environment base_env("package:base");
    Rcpp::Function set_seed_r = base_env["set.seed"];
    set_seed_r(std::floor(std::fabs(seed)));
}

// function r(d, n)
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec randdraw(double d, int n){
    set_seed(d);                                      // Set a seed for R's RNG library
    Rcpp::NumericVector draws = Rcpp::rnorm(n, 0.0, d); // Hook into R's Library
    // Use Armadillo's advanced CTOR to re-use memory and cast as an armadillo object.
    arma::vec out = arma::vec(draws.begin(), n, false, true);
    return out;
}
```

Output:

```
> randdraw(3.21,10)
             [,1]
 [1,] -3.08780627
 [2,] -0.93900757
 [3,]  0.83071017
 [4,] -3.69834335
 [5,]  0.62846287
 [6,]  0.09669786
 [7,]  0.27419092
 [8,]  3.58431878
 [9,] -3.91253230
[10,]  4.06825360
> set.seed(3)
> rnorm(10, 0, 3.21)
 [1] -3.08780627 -0.93900757  0.83071017 -3.69834335  0.62846287  0.09669786  0.27419092  3.58431878 -3.91253230  4.06825360
```

Comment: There is actually more detail behind this.  We already use the R RNG by default, so if you were to draw _uniforms_ you would get the same from R and Armadillo.  Is it just that for _normals_ Armadillo uses its own shuffling so they come out differently.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel,  I've improved the wording a bit to emphasize the shared use of _R_'s RNGs.